# Gson deserialize the boolean JSON only with false, regardless to input

Tags: java, android, json, gson

My object consists of five fields :

```
    public class ConfigurationItem {

    @SerializedName("show_interest")
    boolean show_interest;
    @SerializedName("bid_with_price")
    boolean bid_with_price;
    @SerializedName("anonymous_orders")
    boolean anonymous_orders;
    @SerializedName("orders_progress_status")
    boolean orders_progress_status;
    @SerializedName("orders_progress_messages")
    boolean orders_progress_messages;
}
```

I parse this items from the web server and receive string like this :

```
{
"ordersProgressStatus":true,
"showInterest":false,
"anonymousOrders":true,
"bidWithPrice":true,
"ordersProgressMessages":true
}
```

I receive the JSON and save it to the SharedPreferences like this :

```
public static void saveCurrentConfiguration(Context mContext, JSONObject jsonObject ) {
        SharedPreferences sharedPreferences = mContext.getApplicationContext().getSharedPreferences(Constants.SHARED_PREFS_NAME, Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
            SharedPreferences.Editor prefsEditor = sharedPreferences.edit();
            prefsEditor.putString(Constants.SHARED_CURRENT_CONFIG, jsonObject.toString());
            prefsEditor.apply();
    }
```

But when I want to read the saved object :

```
public static ConfigurationItem getCurrentConfiguration(Context mContext)
{
    SharedPreferences sharedPreferences = mContext.getApplicationContext().getSharedPreferences(Constants.SHARED_PREFS_NAME, Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
    Gson gson = new Gson();
    String json = sharedPreferences.getString(Constants.SHARED_CURRENT_CONFIG, null);
    ConfigurationItem configurationItem = gson.fromJson(json, ConfigurationItem.class);
    Log.i(TAG + " loaded config", configurationItem.toString());
    return configurationItem;
}
```

in the `configurationItem` I get only false values. Besides, the read string from the `SharedPreference` is correct, but when I use `Gson` for deserialize, the object is filled with wrong values.

What can be the solution ?

Comment: I think the JSON object's keys are different, in the `ConfigurationItem` object you've used `show_interest` and the object received has `showInterest`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When using the annotation `@SerializedName` this references the key value in the JSON string. So instead of doing `@SerializedName("show_interest")` to serialize the value from `"showInterest"` do `@SerializedName("showInterest")`

Using serialized name is handy when you don't want to tie the name of a JSON key to name of a field. For instance when you prefer to use the JAVA standaard convention of prefixing private field with `m` like `private boolean mShowInterest;` so when later you refactor the field name to something else you can do a easy refactor, or if the JSON key changes you on have to change the annotation.